# How can I get the parent model data inside of a local scope?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between `$users` and `$students`. A student is considered active if a `$student` has an active status and the `$user` has an active status.

When I call `$user->students()->active` can I get the `$user` model inside of the scope without passing a parameter?. Example below:

```
class User extends Model {
    // Normal model stuff

    function students() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('students', 'user_students');
    }
}

class Student extends Model {
    // Normal model stuff

    function scopeActive($query) {
        // Can I get the $user model here without a parameter?
    }
}
```

So I want to check the users status inside of the `scopeActive` function which will change the query.

Comment: you could store a reference to User in the model?

Comment: @atoms what would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the relationship sounds weird when you try to read it: A user has many students and a student has many users, but anyway.

I don't think that you can get a reference to the caller but you can pass a parameter to a custom scope, those are known as [dynamic scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes)

So your scope can be:

```
public function scopeActive($query, $user)
{
   // here you have reference to the $user
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
Student::active($user);
```

Comment: Yea I agree it's weird but its that way for business reasons. I said above I was after a way without passing a parameter. I was wondering if there was a way to get to the reference to the parent that eloquent uses.